# react redux is not calling dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, dispatcher, dispatch

when I submit the booking form the dispatch action is not calling, I thought is from the redux version but it does work for login and register form. my code looks like

booking.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { clientBooking } from '../store/actions/BookingActions'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

function Booking() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')
  const [style, setStyle] = useState('')
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('')
  const [city, setCity] = useState('')
  const [postalCode, setPostalCode] = useState('')
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('')
  const [age, setAge] = useState('')

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const { client, loading, error } = useSelector((state) => state.clientBooking)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (client) {
      navigate('/')
    }
  }, [client, navigate])

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    dispatch(
      clientBooking(
        name,
        email,
        phone,
        style,
        address,
        city,
        postalCode,
        country,
        age
      )
    )

    setEmail('')

    console.log(
      name,
      email,
      phone,
      style,
      address,
      city,
      postalCode,
      country,
      age
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className='py-16 bg-gray-600'>
      <form
        onSubmit={submitHandler}
        className='grid  justify-items-center gap-y-2 w-full mx-auto '
      >
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='name'
          className='input input-bordered w-5/6  text-black sm:w-1/2 lg:w-96  lg:mr-2  '
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='email'
          className='input input-bordered w-5/6  text-black sm:w-1/2 lg:w-96 lg:mr-2  '
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='phone'
          className='input input-bordered w-5/6  text-black sm:w-1/2 lg:w-96 lg:mr-2  '
          value={phone}
          onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='style'
          className='input input-bordered w-5/6  text-black sm:w-1/2 lg:w-96 lg:mr-2  '
          value={style}
          onChange={(e) => setStyle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='address'
          className='input input-bordered w-5/6 text-black sm:w-1/2 lg:w-96 lg:mr-2 '
          value={address}
          onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='city'
          className='input input-bordered  w-5/6 text-black sm:w-1/2 lg:w-96  lg:mr-2 '
          value={city}
          onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='postCode'
          className='input input-bordered  w-5/6 text-black sm:w-1/2 lg:w-96  lg:mr-2 '
          value={postalCode}
          onChange={(e) => setPostalCode(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='country'
          className='input input-bordered  w-5/6 text-black sm:w-1/2 lg:w-96  lg:mr-2 '
          value={country}
          onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type='number'
          placeholder='age'
          className='input input-bordered w-5/6  text-black sm:w-1/2 lg:w-96  lg:mr-2  '
          value={age}
          onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className='bg-indigo-600 px-5 py-3 rounded-lg w-1/2 sm:w-auto '>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Booking
```

bookingAction.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {
  CLIENT_ORDER_FAIL,
  CLIENT_ORDER_REQUEST,
  CLIENT_ORDER_SUCCESS,
} from '../constants/bookingConstants'

export const clientBooking =
  (name, email, phone, style, address, city, postalCode, country, age) =>
  async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        CLIENT_ORDER_REQUEST,
      })

      const {
        userLogin: { userInfo },
      } = getState()

      const config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
        },
      }

      console.log(
        name,email,phone,style,address,city,postalCode,country,age
      )
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        `/api/clients/`,
        { name, email, phone, style, address, city, postalCode, country, age },
        config
      )

      dispatch({
        type: CLIENT_ORDER_SUCCESS,
        payload: data,
      })
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: CLIENT_ORDER_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message,
      })
    }
  }
```

bookingReducer.js

```
import {
  CLIENT_ORDER_FAIL,
  CLIENT_ORDER_REQUEST,
  CLIENT_ORDER_SUCCESS,
} from '../constants/bookingConstants'

export const clientBookingReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CLIENT_ORDER_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true }
    case CLIENT_ORDER_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, client: action.payload }
    case CLIENT_ORDER_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import {
  userLoginReducer,
  userRegisterReducer,
} from './store/reducers/userReducers'
import { clientBookingReducer } from './store/reducers/bookingReducers'

const reducer = combineReducers({
  userLogin: userLoginReducer,
  userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
  clientBooking: clientBookingReducer,
})

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
  : null

const initialState = {
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
}

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)

export default store
```

I try to change the names of components (eg. booking.js and booking function thinking it might duplicate with react function but still same thing. what could be the wrong while dispatch does work in login and register but not on booking?

Comment: Do `submitHandler` runs? Have you tried to use debugger or at least console.log?

Comment: yeah it does, it console.log it even but does not call the dispatch.